# Gnuplottex basic example fails with 'undefined control sequence'

Tags: pdftex, gnuplot

I'm using latest TeXLive on Linux, and have `gnuplot` installed. I have also installed `gnuplottex` package.

Then, I'm trying to compile the basic [gnuplottex CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gnuplottex) example, [example-pdf.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/gnuplottex/example-pdf.tex); however, I get this:

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex
...
! Undefined control sequence.
\gnuplotverbatimwrite ...e \openout \verbatim@out 
                                                  #1 \BeforeStream \let \do ...
l.7 ...f,terminaloptions={font ",10" linewidth 3}]

? X
```

(full log [here](http://pastebin.com/sixgJXvm))

Anyone have any idea how do I get this basic example to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated the package with the bug fix, should be at a CTAN mirror near you shortly. Thanks guys!

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback, @Lars Kotthoff - moved the accepted answer to yours :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced this error message and used your solution for it. It works very well for smaller documents, meaning less than, say, up to 13 gnuplot-streams in a file.

sadly I experienced a new error in bigger files of my Ph.D. since then: "`no room for a new \write`". This occurs, if you have more than 13 gnuplot figures in your file, in my case currently I have about 30.

But, finally I got a solution for this also, in de.comp.text.tex by Heiko Oberdiek: just change your: `\newwrite\verbatim@out` with: `\@ifundefined{verbatim@out}{\newwrite\verbatim@out}{}%`
This avoids that each gnuplot-stream blocks a write-register and the error will not occur any more.

Comment: Hi @Brinker - many thanks for posting your issue and resolution as well! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it - I think it's an error in the package itself..

First of all, according to the error message above, the '*undefined control sequence*' seems to occur for `\verbatim@out`. I first tried to debug the macros using a `\tracingmacros=1` in the .tex file, but that didn't tell me too much.

Then I read a bit through [verbatim.pdf - A New Implementation of LaTeX's verbatim and verbatim * Environments.](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/verbatim.pdf), and it says:

> As a final nontrivial example we describe the definition of an environment
>   called verbatimwrite. It writes all text in its body to a file whose name is 
>   given as an argument. We assume that a stream number called \verbatim@out has
>   already been reserved by means of the \newwrite macro.

Ahha... well, [gnuplottex.dtx](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.dtx) (and the corresponding `gnuplottex.sty` that gets generated), actually doesn't use `\newwrite` at all!!

So I simply opened my `/PATH/TO/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gnuplottex/gnuplottex.sty` in a text editor, and inserted a `\newwrite\verbatim@out`
 after line 84 - so the code around it now looks like:

```
...
\newcounter{fignum}
\def\figname{\jobname-gnuplottex-fig\thefignum}

\def\gnuplotverbatimwrite#1{%
    \newwrite\verbatim@out % <===== ADDED HERE!!
    \def\BeforeStream
    {\message{Opening gnuplot stream #1}%
        \immediate\write\verbatim@out{\string set terminal \gnuplotterminal \gnuplotterminaloptions}
\immediate\write\verbatim@out{\string set output '\figname.\gnuplottexextension{\gnuplotterminal}'}
    }
    \@bsphack
    \immediate\openout \verbatim@out #1
    \BeforeStream%
...
```

... and now the basic example seems to work :) (*although, I cannot really tell if this is all there is to it :)*)

Cheers!