# GnuplotTex: automatic plotting and vertical line indication

Tags: gnuplot

I am using pdflatex with the `gnuplottex` package, to plot a function with a local maximum; I'd like to find this maximum automatically and label it.

For the most part, I'm already there (*using the special "pseudo" file '`+`' in `gnuplot` >4.4*), apart from a couple of problems -- and I'm not sure whether the problem is in LaTeX or `gnuplot` ... Here is a minimal working example:

```
% build with:
% pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex

\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter\newwrite\verbatim@out\makeatother
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

Here a brief test...

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{gnuplot}[scale=0.95]
  # Define helper functions
  ismax(x) = (x>max)?max=x:0
  isxmax(x) = (ismax(f(x))!=0)?xmax=x:0 #

  # Initialise the 'global' vars
  max=-1e38
  xmax=-1e38
  min=1e38
  ymaxrange=0.05 # added

  set grid
  set title 'gnuplottex test'
  set ylabel '$y$'
  set xlabel '$x$'
  set xrange [0:2000]
  set yrange [0:ymaxrange] # MUST set this!

  # define the function
  f(x) = (20*x)/(100000 + 50*x + x**2)

  set multiplot

  # plot f(x) # OK, works as usual

  # to turn off the annoying label in the upper right corner - also f($0) will cause latex crash
  set nokey

  # plot the function - which will also calculate xmax (first pass)

  plot '+' using ($1):(f($1)) with linespoints,       '+' using ($1):(isxmax($1)) with lines linecolor 2
  # '+' using ($1):(ismax(f($1))) with lines linecolor 2


  # second part of plot - which needs xmax

  set grid noxtics noytics # prevent double plot ?!
  set arrow from xmax,0 to xmax,3 nohead lt 1 linewidth 2 # linewidth doesn't change ?!

  set label "X" at xmax,f(xmax)
  set label "(%.0f;",xmax,"%f)",f(xmax) at 0.6*xmax,f(xmax)+ymaxrange/10

  plot '+' using ($1)
  # replot # nope, doubles
  unset multiplot
\end{gnuplot}
\end{figure}


500 1000 1500 ... End of test.

\end{document}
```

This code results with a rendering like this (which is a screenshot of `evince` rendering the PDF):

[image: gnuplottex test]

And these are my problems:

- It seems that upon execution of the second `plot`, the labels and axes get repeated on top of each other, in spite of a `set grid noxtics noytics` (*notice they are a bit darker in the screenshot*) -- can this be prevented?
- In principle, without the `set yrange ...` line, the second `plot` may contain a different automatic range (though that is not visible in this example). Is there a way to "copy"/duplicate a range of an axis that was computed automatically in `gnuplot`?
- the `linewidth` (`lw`) argument of `set arrow` (which is for implementing a vertical line) seems not to have any effect -- how can I manipulate that?
- The line from `set arrow` and the (very thin dotted) line from the `isxmax($1)` plot do not match; seemingly it is the `arrow` that is off -- how to fix this?
- The `linecolor` argument seems to have no effect -- how to fix this? (*btw, color seems to work fine for `\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf,...`, however, I'd like to keep the LaTeX 'terminal'*)

References:

- [Re: Calculate the minimum and maximum data with 'Gnuplot'](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/2008-05/msg00186.html)
- [Drawing vertical lines with gnuplot...impossible? - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1220309)
- [How do I draw a vertical line in gnuplot ? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457046/how-do-i-draw-a-vertical-line-in-gnuplot/4457102#comment-6589749)
- [Gnuplottex basic example fails with 'undefined control sequence' ?!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16393/gnuplottex-basic-example-fails-with-undefined-control-sequence)
- [Gnuplot tricks: Plot iterations and pseudo-files](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2010/01/plot-iterations-and-pseudo-files.html)
- [Gnuplot (notes)](http://sparky.rice.edu/gnuplot.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `pgfplots` package for this. You can generate the data with gnuplot by using `\addplot gnuplot {<expression>};`, and then read the generated data using `\pgfplotstableread{\jobname.pgf-plot.table}\table`. After sorting this table, you just access the first element, which now contains the local maximum.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=0.05,xmin=0,xmax=2000,grid=both]

\addplot [domain={0:2000},samples=1000]
  gnuplot {(20*x)/(100000 + 50*x + x**2)};

\pgfplotstableread{\jobname.pgf-plot.table}\table
\pgfplotstablesort[sort cmp={float >},sort key={[index] 1}]\sorted{\table}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index] 1}\of{\sorted}
\let\maxy=\pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index] 0}\of{\sorted}
\let\maxx=\pgfplotsretval


\node at (axis cs:\maxx,\maxy)
  [circle, fill, red,inner sep=1.5pt,
   pin={
    [fill=white]40:{(\pgfmathprintnumber{\maxx}, \pgfmathprintnumber{\maxy}})
   }
  ] {};
\draw [red] (axis cs:\maxx,0) -- (axis cs:\maxx,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: finding the local maximum using pgpflots]

Comment: Hi @Jake - thanks a lot for this answer! It seems like the optimal solution that will utilize the gnuplot syntax...

Answer (score 4):

Many of your questions concern how GnuPlot constructs graphs and don't have much to do with TeX. Unless there are some GnuPlot experts around here, more insight may be found on their mailing list:

> http://groups.google.com/group/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot

As for not getting colored output from the `latex` terminal---that question I can answer: The GnuPlot `latex` terminal does not include any color information into the `picture` code that it generates. You need to use a different terminal.

---

#### The `epslatex` terminal:

```
\begin{gnuplot}[scale=0.95,terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
```

If using `pdflatex`, you will also need to convert the resulting EPS files to PDF. This can be done by installing the `epstopdf` tool and adding the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[suffix=]{epstopdf}
```

However, feeding EPS to `pdflatex` just feels like a hack.  There are other GnuPlot terminals you can use to get around this.

---

#### The `tikz` terminal:

```
\begin{gnuplot}[scale=0.95,terminal=tikz,terminaloptions=createstyle]
```

You also need to change the upper y value on your `arrow` from:

```
set arrow from xmax,0 to xmax,3 nohead lt 1 linewidth 2
```

To:

```
set arrow from xmax,0 to xmax,ymaxrange nohead lt 1 linewidth 2
```

Or it will shoot off into space.

The following has to be added to the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
  % Tell gunuplottex to bring TikZ output in using \input rather
  % than \includegraphics
  \def\gnuplottexextension@tikz{\string tex}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz} % Generated by the createstyle option
```

The results are:

[image: GnuPlot TikZ output]

---

Other GnuPlot terminals that may be of interest generate Metapost and PS-Tricks output.

Comment: Hi @Sharpie, thanks a lot for the detailed color and terminals explanation! I guess, I wanted to use a `gnuplot` syntax for function plotting, along with calculation of a max value - and yet have the whole thing coded in a Latex file (i.e. without intermediary image files) ... Cheers!