# latex code for graphing rational function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, plot

I've seen in `TikZ` and `pgf` Manual for version 1.18 a code for graphing some functions but it does not provide an example for a rational function.

Can someone help me graph `$x+\frac{1}{x}$`?

Comment: Did you look at [Plot reciprocal function with tkiz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20924/1952)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick adaptation from example from p. 225 (section 19.5) of `pgfmanual` (for version 2.10).  Notice that due to a singularity at zero I gave the formula twice; I do not know whether this can be avoided.  (Well, it *can*, by giving the domain and the number of samples so that no sample is taken at zero, but this would be *far* from elegant!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-3.1,-4.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \draw[->] (-3.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-4.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[color=orange,domain=-3:-0.3] plot (\x,{\x+1/\x});
  \draw[color=orange,domain=0.3:3] plot (\x,{\x+1/\x}) node[right] {$y = x+\frac{1}{x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as mbork's answer but with `pgfplots`, just for academic purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    grid=major,
    xmin=-3.1,xmax=3.9,
    ymin=-4.1,ymax=3.9,
    restrict y to domain=-4:4,
    %unbounded coords=jump,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    clip=false]
  \addplot[color=orange,domain=-3:3,samples=100] {x+1/x} node[right] {$y = x+\frac{1}{x}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]