# gnuplot true standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, standalone

Finally I have decided to go PDF. I can add pictures without EPS wrapper, and do drawings with TikZ - life is good :o)

But how do I use [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)? For consistency I would like to use the `tikz` terminal, and I would like to be able to preview my graphs without including them in a document. This

```
set term tikz standalone preamble '\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}'
set output "test.tex"
plot x title '\ce{H2O}'
```

will make an `article` class document that can compile alone, but it can not be included in another document.

One solution would be *not* to use the `standalone` option, and then make a small script, that wraps the output in the [`standalone` class](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone). Now the document can compile alone, and it can be included in a document, but I would not be able to specify an additional preamble. :o(

Does anyone have a smart solution?

Comment: Did you try [KtikZ (QtikZ)](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/)  ? You can edit the preamble of the compiling document for further modifications.

Comment: I would recommend you use PGFplots, which can use gnuplots to do the calculations, but creates the plots directly in your LaTeX document.

Comment: Apropos of @Jake's comment, `tikz` itself has a `\draw plot function {...};` operator that passes the braced function straight to `gnuplot`.  See the 2.10 manual, section 19.6.

Comment: I think that Hans-Peter wants to work initially in gnuplot to figure out the plot parameters and stuff, and only go to TeX for when it is to be included in the document. Am I right? In which case a simple script to strip out the preamble would seem simplest. Can you post a typical file from gnuplot? Both with and without the preamble stuff.

Comment: I would like to tryout QtikZ(if nothing else - just for the fun of it). I am on a mac, and I read here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633/is-there-any-way-to-get-real-time-compilation-for-latex that 'brew install qt' should do something - what!?

Comment: As Andrew writes, I wold like to do my plots within gnuplot(I like automatic axes, tics, titles,...)- making a script which output does not need further editing before inclusion(so I can rerun the script, if my data changes).

Comment: @AndrewStacey: How do I post files?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: You can edit your question to include example code. I would still recommend PGFplots instead of using Gnuplot's TikZ terminal. It has all the automatic plot features, but it generates much nicer legends and titles, and in my experience it's easier to annotate your plots.

Comment: Perhaps a solution is to use `gnuplottex`

Comment: Take a look at [an answer I gave](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35549/9043) to a question on plotting. Lower down it shows how to plot data from a file. It would be trivial to have a minimal document with `pgfplots` to test your plots before putting them into a main document.

Comment: @Jake : Don't you mean that TikZ does _not_ have all the automatic plot features?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: No, PGFplots (which uses TikZ for the drawing, and which can use gnuplot in the background for the calculations) *does* have all the features.

Comment: @jake : Can I read about these features(axis, tics,...) somewhere in the pgfmanual.pdf?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: [PGFplots](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/) is a different package that is built on top of TikZ. The manual is [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `standalone`and `gnuplottex`you can get only the picture but `pgfplots` is preferable because it's hard to manage the font for the labels between `gnuplot` and `latex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[]{gnuplottex} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}       
  \begin{gnuplot}
      plot x title '\ce{H2O}'
  \end{gnuplot}        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oooh - I think that is a solution. Instead of writing a gnuplot script, I write in  latex using gnuplot. But I can still use the TikZ terminal!

Comment: :I can not compile your example - when trying `pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex`, I get `! Undefined control sequence.
\gnuplotverbatimwrite ...e \openout \verbatim@out 
                                                  #1 \BeforeStream \let \do ...
l.7       p
           lot x title '\ce{H2O}'`

Comment: I managed to compile the example after editing the gnuplottex.sty as described by sdaau here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16393/gnuplottex-basic-example-fails-with-undefined-control-sequence