# Gnuplottex fails with 'undefined control sequence' when choosing different font size

Tags: fonts, graphics, errors, miktex, gnuplot

I encounter a very strange problem when using gnuplottex on my Win 7 32 bit system with MiKTeX 2.9 - gnuplot 4.6.3 & the latest gnuplottex release:

```
\documentclass[dvips]{minimal}

\newcommand{\sz}{\small}

\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pslatex,terminaloptions={dashed auxfile}]
set xlabel '\sz{Test x}'
plot sin(x)
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

Here are the last lines of my log file:

```
Opening gnuplot stream test-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot
runsystem(gnuplot test-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot)...executed.

Package gnuplottex Info: test-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot converted on input line 1
8.

(D:\notebooks\data\cmds\test-gnuplottex-fig1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
\sz ->\small 

l.10 ...9,140){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}\sz{Test x}}}
                                                  %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

) [1] (D:\notebooks\data\cmds\test.aux) )
```

Was is going wrong here? This is weird, since some days ago it worked and it seems to me that I didn't change something...

If you just use

```
\newcommand{\sz}{}
```

everything's fine.

The same message was encountered here: [Gnuplottex basic example fails with 'undefined control sequence'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16393/gnuplottex-basic-example-fails-with-undefined-control-sequence) but it was solved by updating the package.

Every suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Comment: @egreg: it should _only_ be avoided when a font problem appears. In other cases it is _very_ useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the documentclass `minimal` doesn't know anything about fontsize macros. Use `article` instead. However, `\small` has no argument, it is a switch. Use

```
{\sz Test x}
```

And, by the way, the error message comes from LaTeX not Gnuplot